# Naming conventions for static methods, when the class name can be a verb

Tags: java, static, naming-conventions

I have a class called `Load`, which will contain some static methods for loading resources.

The word "Load" can be both a noun and a verb. So, let's say I want two methods, one to load "Space Files" and one to load "Ocean Files" as an example.

Now, I know that methods should typically be named in such a way where they contain a verb, or describe an action. So, good names for them would be `loadSpaceFiles` and `loadOceanFiles`.

However, I understand that good, clean code should try to read like a sentence. The end result of using those names would be code that looks like this:

```
Load.loadSpaceFiles
//
Load.loadOceanFiles
```

If I exclude the "load" from the method names, I'll have code like this:

```
Load.spaceFiles
//
Load.oceanFiles
```

And that reads much nicer. However, the method names suffer a result, since without the context of the `Load` class, the method names don't describe the action of the method.

What's considered the best naming convention in this scenario?

Comment: Why not call the class `Loader` instead?

Comment: @William yeah that is another option. In fact, maybe it's better to go with that.

Comment: I call it `Loaders` and use the `load...` methods. Everything is obvious then.